# Client-socket programming in Java - trouble with writing to the client socket from server side

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, readline, println

So I am trying to create a simple server client program, where multiple clients can connect to a single server. I'm running a thread on both client side and server side. I have a file "loginuser.txt" which has text for 5 lines. This code is the server thread. When I call a outToClient.println("xxx") or anything, the Client is NOT receiving MORE than ONE line at a time. Each time the user enters anything on the keyboard (on client terminal), the next line of the file is being displayed on the same terminal. Can someone tell me why this is happening? Where am I going wrong? 
Basic issue: For a println() of a single line from server to client, it seems like I have to type something every time on the client side.

```
BufferedReader inFromUser=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
BufferedReader inFromClient=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader userlogr=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("loginuser.txt"));
PrintWriter outToClient = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
if(check==1)
    {
        fromclient=inFromClient.readLine();
        if(fromclient.compareTo("xxx")==0)
        {
            String line;
            while((line=userlogr.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                outToClient.println(line);
                outToClient.flush();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like the client is the problem. It's in a loop where it's pausing for input and you have only one thread handling both user input and receiving data from the server.  Edit your post and show the client code as well.

Comment: Sounds like a protocol issue (your protocol). My guess is that the client only reads one line for every line it sends. If you want to send multiple lines in one response you need to have some other way to know when you have received the entire message.

Comment: Can you show the respective client code?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before. There are usually three things

1.)Also check the strings your sending has **"\n"** at the end. using \n and println would mess up the carriage return since it would be doubled.Remove any extra "\n" and try it.(High possibility this is the problem in your case)

2.) The client side does not have a while loop to output the entire data being passed. You are sending the data line by line. Check if the client is closing itself after the data is received.

3.) Check your **threads** on the client side. I do not know how your client side thread works, but mine used to get blocked by other threads.